# xsl replace one link with another

Tags: xslt

I manage a site which was owned by one organization (ie www.old.com) and has now been replaced with a new organization (ie www.new.com). My problem is that some of the links still point to the old organization on some of the images we use on the site. I was wondering if there was a way to replace http://www.old.com with http://www.new.com using xsl.

My thought was doing this but not sure if it will work..

```
 <xsl:template match="image">
<xsl:param name ="old" value='http://www.old.com'/>
 <xsl:param name ="new" value='http://www.new.com'/>
  <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="contains(@xlink:href,$old)">
            <xsl:attribute name="xlink:href">
              <xsl:value-of select="replace(@xlink:href, $old, $new)">
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:attribute name="xlink:href">
              <xsl:value-of select="@xlink:href"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

The xml looks like this..

```
<book title="Harry Potter">
 <description
 xlink:type="simple"
  xlink:href="http://www.old.com/images/HPotter.gif"
  xlink:show="new">
 As his fifth year at Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and
 Wizardry approaches, 15-year-old Harry Potter is.......
  </description>
</book>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is your source XML? Looks like you're matching against `<image link="http://..."/>` but that is not HTML; you're not creating an `img` element, and even then, it should be a `src` attribute and not a  `href` attribute. Please specify input and output format more clearly.

Comment: Hi. I should have used xlink instead of link. *DOOF!!* My xml looks something like this (I don't have the source code in front of me at the moment but this is a good example of it)..<book title="Harry Potter">
  <description
  xlink:type="simple"
  xlink:href="http://book.com/images/HPotter.gif"
  xlink:show="new">
  As his fifth year at Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and
  Wizardry approaches, 15-year-old Harry Potter is.......
  </description>
</book>

Comment: In the sample you gave in the comment, the XSL template would not even match...

Comment: Fixed the xsl and added the xml to the example. Hopefully its correct. But, I am a newbie so I am not 100% sure

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0? @Lucero's solution assumes the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming an `apply-templates` that traverses all nodes (see first template below), the following should work:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@xlink:href">
  <xsl:param name ="old">http://www.old.com</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name ="new">http://www.new.com</xsl:param>
  <xsl:attribute name="xlink:href">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., $old, $new)"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will have to add a <choose><xsl:when test = "contains (., $old)"> ...</when> <otherwise> .. </otherwise> </choose> because some of the xml contains http://www.old.com and some contain http://www.new.com so I need the code to test which is which and apply the proper value of "@xlink:href"

Comment: No, replace will only replace if it finds a match, making the call to `contains` unnecessary. The semantics are the same.

Comment: ok. I didn't know that. I will let you know how it works when I test it at work tomorrow. Thanks for your help today.